# changing one of the unique names inside a vector in R

Tags: r

I have dataset$SITE which has 100 rows containing unique elements "North", "South" and "East Bar". How can I change all the rows with "East Bar" to "East"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `dataset$SITE` is a `factor`, then you want to do as @DavidRobinson suggests.
Otherwise, you want to use the following.

```
 dataset$SITE[dataset$SITE == "East Bar"] <- "East"
```

---

Note, one of the many ways to check if you're dealing with a factor:

```
  is.factor(dataset$SITE)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
levels(dataset$SITE)[1] = "East"
```

Comment: Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, data.Int$INTERVIEW_SITE == "Pegleg Bar",  :
  invalid factor level, NAs generated

Comment: Then this is a factor, not a character vector. What do you get when you do `levels(dataset$SITE)`? (I'm guessing something like `[1] "East Bar" "North" "South"`?)

Comment: [1] "North"   "South"   "East Bar"